# Is there a way to count the number of "_" (Underscore) present in a string using Dynamic content editor in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

For example here is a file name "foo_foo1_foo_foo2.csv" . I would like to extract the number of "_" present in the text, here it should return 3.

Comment: can't you just call an azure function which will do that for you?

Comment: Actually it is part of a pipeline where i have to verify the naming convention of a file. That is why doing it using a set variable activity and Dynamic editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick demo that i created.

**Main idea:**

get file name from '**Get Metadata**' activity, and send it as a parameter to the dataflow, in dataflow we will use '**Assert**' activity (or filter depends on your use case for the sake of this demo i used the Assert activity).

Pre-requisites:

created a file called: `foo_foo1_foo_foo2.json`, saved it in a storage account under a container called '`testsally`' and a subfolder called '`files`'.

i added this file as a dataset in ADF like so:
[image: ![enter image description here]

so basically here, I'm selecting the file under 'files' subfolder.
ADF:

- **Pipeline activities**:

  - Get Metadata : here i added item name , which is the file name that we will use later on in our dataflow.
    [image]
- **DataFlow parameters**:
  i added a parameter '`filename`' with a value of : `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName`
- **DataFlow Activities**:
- added a derived column, with the file name from the parameter that we defined above.
  [image]
- added an assert activity (you can replace it with a filter depends on your usecase) , in Expression i added this code: `equals(size(split($filename,'_')),3)`
  [image]
  this activity will mark to us if the file name has 3 underscores.

**Data preview in assert activity:**

[image]

the green mark on the left is an indicator that file name matches the rule that we defined.

**DataFlow activities:**
[image]

**Pipeline**:
[image]

You can read more about the assert activity here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-assert